# Azure Log analytics simple pie chart

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I have a query like;

example_CL
| where field1 == "name" 
| top 1 by TimeGenerated desc

Gives me the latest row with the latest value of "name" like;

```
name        quota   used
samplename  100     75
```

I'm trying to make a donut chart which shows 75/100.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

would this work?

```
datatable(field1:string, quota:int, used:int)
[
    "somename", 100, 75
]
| project used, unsued = quota - used
| evaluate narrow()
| project Column, toint(Value)
| render piechart
```

[image]

Comment: Also, do you know how I can set a metric measurement alert for the query above incase the used % is higher than 90 % of quota?

Comment: I've personally haven't used Log Analytics, but if I had to, I would try going with the instructions detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-unified-log

Comment: `evaluate narrow()` "unpivots" a wide table (ie, your data row) into a table with three columns. Then you project on 2 columns with `project Column, toint(Value)`. Thank you for this.